# TelephonyManager returns null in fragment

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am trying to get Device Id from Telephony Manager in my app but I am getting null pointer exception. I debugged it and TelephonyManger object is null when instantiated. I found few solutions regarding this but I have already done all that things. I have also given appropriate permission in manifest file.

Here is my code

```
TelephonyManager TM=(TelephonyManager)getActivity. getSystemService(android.cotent.Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
id=TM.getDeviceId();
```

Permission in manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for [getSystemService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.Class%3CT%3E%29) says that it may return null if it's not a supported system service.  So you should *always* check for null in this case and deal with it accordingly.

Comment: I checked for it and it returns true

Comment: Um, no you didn't.  Unless you are showing the wrong code.

Comment: I checked using hasSystemFeature and it returns true

Comment: You're still not showing the code.  I have no idea what you're checking and what you expect to happen.

Comment: `PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
boolean hasTelephony=pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);`
hasTelephony returns true

Comment: Where in the documentation are you seeing that check should guarantee that the service returns non-null?  It could be a problem with the device.

Comment: Never mind now. I got the solution. Problem is that I was testing it in a phone without sim card but with device having sim card it is showing device id

Comment: So, like I said in my answer, you should always check for null.